# Why didn't the Jews understand "Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani"?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew, crucifixion, jews, aramaic

> And about the ninth hour Jesus cried out with a loud voice, saying, "Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani?" that is, "My God, My God, why have You forsaken Me?"
>
> Some of those who stood there, when they heard *that*, said, "This Man is calling for Elijah!" (Matthew 27:46-47, NKJV)

According to a number of sites, including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_of_Jesus#Eli_Eli_lema_sabachthani_.28.CE.97.CE.BB.CE.AF_.CE.97.CE.BB.CE.AF_.CE.BB.CE.B9.CE.BC.CE.AC_.CF.83.CE.B1.CE.B2.CE.B1.CF.87.CE.B8.CE.B1.CE.BD.CE.AF.29), the saying "Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani" (or in Mark's version "Eloi, Eloi, lama sabachthani") was originally Aramaic:

> אלהי אלהי למא שבקתני.
>
> <sub>Courtesy of Wikipedia</sub>

However, according to some other sites it is Hebrew.

Regardless of which is right, I don't think it can be denied that the Jews mistook what he said. I used to take this to mean that he was speaking in a language they did not understand. However, as far as I know and have learned from our good friend Google, Jews at that time spoke both Hebrew *and* Aramaic (plus some Greek, and perhaps Latin).

How, then, did the Jews mistake his meaning?

Comment: Great question. My *guess* is that, having been beaten, lashed, had a crown of thorns pushed into His head, struck on the head more than once, crucified and left to hang there for a least three hours, with nails in His hands and feet, His speech was less than clear.

Comment: Excellent question. This might receive some answers maybe on the History.SE

Comment: Just a guess here but ELIjah might have had something to do with it. Also, Elijah is invoked fairly regularly in Judaism. It's kind of like how Christians invoke the second coming of Christ.

Comment: I have a couple of interesting answers here, yet they are both so different it is hard to decide which one is the most accurate. I'm just not going to accept either for the moment, and will be looking forward to more answers, that is if anyone else thinks they can add anything to what has been said.

Comment: I think we also need to understand that nobody was at the foot of the cross as we often see.  People were far from the cross while the execution was proceeding.

Comment: See [Prayers of Jews to Angels and Other Intermediaries during the First Centuries CE](http://faculty.biu.ac.il/~barilm/articles/publications/publications0079.html), by Meir Bar-Ilan.

Answer (score 16):

There are two basic theories here. The first is that the crowd misheard Jesus.  The second is that they purposefully twisted his words to mock him.  Commentators are fairly evenly split on which option is more probable.

### Misheard

In the first view, the crowd was at a significant enough distance that they could not hear Jesus clearly.  Additionally, those in the crowd may have been poorly educated and/or Hellenists and therefore did not have a strong command over the Hebrew/Aramaic.  Thus when Jesus said "Eloi" (Mark)/"Eli" (Matthew) their brains interpreted as "Elias" (=Elijah).   In support of how this would be an easy mistake to make, *Ellicott's Commentary* cites Matthew 16:14 and Matthew 17:10 which show that it was a common expectation during Jesus' time that Elijah would return at the coming of the Messiah (in reference to Malachi 4:5).

> The dominant expectation of the coming of Elijah would predispose men to fasten on the similarity of sound, and the strange unearthly darkness would intensify the feeling that looked for a supernatural manifestation of His presence.

A couple previous answers mention the idea that those who misheard were Roman soldiers.  While it is probable there were Romans present, and some commentators have suggested the comment comes from Romans, that is not very likely.  While the soldiers may have had some basic understanding of Aramaic, it is not likely they would have knowledge of Elijah, much less automatically thought of him when they heard someone crying out in anguish.

### Purposely distorted

The other option is that the crowd heard Jesus alright but seized on the opportunity to mock Jesus.  In this view, the crowd was referencing the same Messianic prophecy (Malachi 4:5), but were essentially saying "even Jesus realizes the prophecy was not fulfilled."  *Barnes' Notes* writes:

> The taunt would be more cutting, because it was the universal belief of the Jews, as well as the doctrine of Christ, that "Elias" would come before the Messiah. They derided him now, as calling upon "Elias" when God would not help him; still keeping up the pretensions to being the Messiah, and invoking "Elijah" to come from the dead to aid him.

The entire mock trial-crucifixion episode has been about demeaning Jesus, so it is certainly possible that it ends on one last note of mocking.

### Analysis

In my view, a simple misunderstanding is more likely.  In Matthew, the episode continues:

> And some of the bystanders, hearing it, said, “This man is calling Elijah.” And one of them at once ran and took a sponge, filled it with sour wine, and put it on a reed and gave it to him to drink. But the others said, “Wait, let us see whether Elijah will come to save him.” (Matthew 27:47-49, ESV)

It seems that the man offering up the sponge probably heard Jesus correctly and understood He was suffering and tried to help.  The statement by the rest to "wait and see" could be read as further mocking, but to me more naturally suggests a initial misunderstanding, followed by doubt that Elijah would actually come without fully ruling out the possibility.

As the *Pulpit Commentary* points out, the fact that the insult theory relies on a Jewish audience purposefully distorting the name of God also creates a significant difficulty:

> The time of ribaldry and abuse is now past; the supernatural darkness has had a calming and terrifying effect; and there is no spirit of mockery left in the awed bystanders. Besides this, it is not likely that Jews, who with all their errors and vices paid an outward respect to holy things, would have presumed to make a play on the sacred name of God.

Answer (score 10):

If the narrative is followed from verse 35, one will note that the Roman soldiers were present throughout, they “sitting down they watched him”.  Note not all but “some of them that stood there…said, this man calleth for Elias”.  Spoken by a Roman soldiers that did not know Aramaic.

> Matthew 27:35 And they crucified him, and parted his garments, casting lots: that it might be fulfilled which was spoken by the prophet, They parted my garments among them, and upon my vesture did they cast lots. **And sitting down they watched him there**;
>
> 27:46…And about the ninth hour Jesus cried with a loud voice, saying, Eli, Eli, lama sabachthani? that is to say, My God, my God, why hast thou forsaken me? Some of them that stood there, when they heard that, said, **This man calleth for Elias.And straightway one of them ran, and took a spunge, and filled it with vinegar**, and put it on a reed, and gave him to drink.The rest said, Let be, let us see whether Elias will come to save him.
>
> 27:54..Now when the **centurion**, and they that were with him, watching Jesus, saw the earthquake, and those things that were done, they feared greatly, saying, **Truly this was the Son of God**.

The comment came from the ones that "took a spunge, and filled it with vinegar", a non-Jew!

> Luke 23:36 "And the **soldiers** also mocked him, coming to him, and **offering him vinegar"**

Comment: Would the centurions have known of Elijah (or expected him to come)?

Comment: Romans were aware of many belief systems, this was a big event.  They likely knew enough to make an uninformed comment.

Comment: Only "some" thought he was calling for Elijah--not all.

Comment: @Narnian, Yes that makes sense to me

Comment: How do we know that the one who "took a sponge, and filled it with vinegar" was a Roman soldier?

Comment: @Rick - perhaps; we do know there were many non-Romans in the close vicinity of the crucifixion, though. I was under the [maybe mistaken] impression that friends and family of the condemned were able to "intervene" in a comforting manner (eg via supplying a drink) to the dying (just like the hangers-on in British hangings years back).

Comment: @warren, Note Luke 23:36 "And the soldiers also mocked him, coming to him, and offering him vinegar"

Answer (score 9):

"Eli Eli lama sabachthani?" is Greek transliteration of Aramaic words. If it was Hebrew, then azabthani would have been used instead of Aramaic word "Sabachthani."

Check this link for Hebrew NT of Matthew 27.

http://www.bayithamashiyach.com/Matthew_27.pdf

In Hebrew, "Eli Eli lama sabachthani?" will become "Eliy ‘Eliy lamah `azab’taniy?"

Here is an explanation I found on why people thought Jesus was calling for Elijah.

"Jesus Christ was suffering horrendous pain for about SIX HOURS. He called out for “Eli”, His exhaustion and heavy breathing could have caused Him to add an “ah” on the end. Try talking when you have gone for a long run and you’ll see what I mean. “Eli-ah” sounds a lot like “Eliyah” does it not?" (Source - http://ellhn.e-e-e.gr/books/assets/NewTestament.pdf on Page. 52)

Eliya (also written as Eliyah in English) is Aramaic for "Elijah." (Source - Mark 15:35 of Aramaic Peshitta New Testament)

I also want to point out that the spoken language of first century Israel was Aramaic. Not Hebrew or Greek. This is confirmed by New Testament and Jewish Historian Josephus.

Jewish Historian Josephus states that Jews didn't speak Greek in first century Israel.

Jewish Historian Josephus wrote:

> "**I have also taken a great deal of pains to obtain the learning of the Greeks, and understand the elements of the Greek language, although I have so long accustomed myself to speak our own tongue, that I cannot pronounce Greek with sufficient exactness; for our nation does not encourage those that learn the languages of many nations, and so adorn their discourses with the smoothness of their periods**; because they look upon this sort of accomplishment as common, not only to all sorts of free-men, but to as many of the servants as please to learn them. But they give him the testimony of being a wise man who is fully acquainted with our laws, and is able to interpret their meaning; **on which account, as there have been many who have done their endeavors with great patience to obtain this learning, there have yet hardly been so many as two or three that have succeeded therein, who were immediately well rewarded for their pains**." - Antiquities of Jews XX, XI

Jewish Wars (Book 1, Preface, Paragraph 1) -

> "I have proposed to myself, for the sake of such as live under the government of the Romans, **to translate those books into the Greek tongue, which I formerly composed in the language of our country, and sent to the Upper Barbarians**. Joseph, the son of Matthias, by birth a Hebrew, a priest also, and one who at first fought against the Romans myself, and was forced to be present at what was done afterwards, [am the author of this work]."

Also note the names in English Bible of New Testament - "Bar"tholomew, "Bar"abbas, "Bar"nabbas, "Bar"sabbas, "Bar" Jesus, Simon "Bar" Jonah, "Bar" Timaeus, etc.

Aramaic word Bar means Son. In Hebrew, Ben means Son. For example, Benjamin in Old Testament, and First Israeli Prime Minister, David Ben Gurion.

Acts 1:19

> "And it became known to **all the inhabitants of Jerusalem, so that the field was called in their own language Akeldama, that is, Field of Blood**."

"Akel dama" is Greek transliteration of Aramaic words "Khqel Dama." "Khqel Dama" is also written as Hakel Dama in English.

We clearly see "Field of Blood" was called "Khqel Dama" by **all the inhabitants of Jerusalem in their own language which is Aramaic**.

If I translate aramaic words "Khqel Dama" into Hebrew, then "Khqel Dama" will become "Sh'deh Hadam."

Through this, we can read that all inhabitants of Jerusalem spoke in their own language in first century AD which was Aramaic. If Hebrew was used as spoken language in first century Israel, then "Sh'deh Hadam" would have been mentioned along with "Khqel Dama" (a.k.a akel dama in Greek and English NT) in Acts 1:19.

Here is the link to Acts Chapter 1 (Hebrew translation from Greek)

http://www.bayithamashiyach.com/Acts_1.pdf

You will see "s'deh Hadam" at the end of Acts 1:19. To match the words, see S'deh (Green color) and Field (Green Color). Hadam (in purple color) and Blood (in purple color).

Josephus' Antiquities of Jews 3:32 - Now the Hebrews call this food manna; for the particle man, **in our language**, is the asking of a question, What is this?

"Man" is Aramaic. In Hebrew, Aramaic word "Man" will become "Mah".

According to Dead Sea Scrolls archaeologist, Yigael Yadin, Aramaic was the language of Jews until Simon bar Kokhba tried to revive Hebrew and make Hebrew as the official language of Jews during Bar Kokhba revolt (132-135 AD). Yigael Yadin noticed the shift from Aramaic to Hebrew during the time of Bar Kokhba revolt (132 - 135 AD). In Yigael Yadin's book "Bar Kokhba: The rediscovery of the legendary hero of the last Jewish Revolt Against Imperial Rome", Yadin notes,

> "It is interesting that the earlier documents are written in Aramaic while the later ones are in Hebrew. Possibly the change was made by a special decree of Bar-Kokhba who wanted to restore Hebrew as the official language of the state" (page 181).

In Book "A Roadmap to the Heavens: An Anthropological Study of Hegemony among Priests, Sages, and Laymen (Judaism and Jewish Life)" by Sigalit Ben-Zion (Page 155), Yadin remarked: "**it seems that this change came as a result of the order that was given by Bar Kokhba, who wanted to revive the Hebrew language and make it the official language of the state**."

According to Book "Naming the Witch: Magic, Ideology, and Stereotype in the Ancient World" written by Kimberly B. Stratton (p. 232), Yadin suggests that Bar Kokhba was trying to revive Hebrew by decree as part of his messianic ideology.

Comment: Very convincing answer. However I noticed that you dealt mostly with trying to prove that Aramaic was the actual spoken language. While that is great, and I appreciated that, could you try to explain a little more on the actual question? I see you said "Here is an explanation I found"... Where did you find it? It is nice if you add references for everything you quote.

Comment: Sure. I am going to add a link.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, there were Romans who were present at the Crucifixion, so its possible that the phrase "Some of those who stood there..." in v. 47 is referring to the Romans. Also, it could refer to Hellenized Jews. These are the Jews who lived outside of Palestine in other parts of the Roman Empire. They usually did not speak Hebrew or Aramaic. Instead, they spoke Greek. But most still visited Palestine for the Pilgrimage feasts (Passover, Pentecost, and The Festival of Tabernacles) as required by the Law of Moses (Torah).

So the phrase "Some of those who stood there" in verse 47 who misunderstood what Jesus was saying is probably referring to the Romans and the Hellenized Jews who were present and not the Palestinian Jews who lived in Palestine at the time and spoke both Aramaic and Hebrew.

Although some may deny the existence of Hellenized Jews in the ancient world (I only know of one person!), their existence is affirmed in the New Testament in Acts 2 (all the Jews in Pentecost heard the Apostles in their own languages, meaning they didn't all speak Hebrew and Aramaic) and in Acts 6 (where there is a dispute between the Hellenized Jews and the Palestinian Jews). The Septuagint (A Greek translation of the Old Testament) was translated a few hundred years before Christ because most of the Jews outside of Palestine no longer spoke Hebrew. This ancient translation also serves to indicate the existence of Hellenized Jews well before the time of Christ.

Comment: Jews didn't speak either Greek or Hebrew in first century Israel. In Judea, Hebrew was only preserved for religious purposes by Jewish Priests. Since nobody "spoke" Hebrew, they used Aramaic Old Testament known as Aramaic Peshitta Tanakh. Jews outside Palestine spoke Aramaic as their language. There were no Hellenized Jews - check Josephus' Antiquities of Jews XX XI and Jewish Wars Book 1 Preface Paragraph 1.

Comment: @konwayk Generally when Josephus refers to Jews he is not referring to Hellenized Jews. As a priest, he saw these Jews as having been assimilated and giving up their Jewish heritage. Its an example of the No True Scotsman fallacy. According to the Jewish Encyclopedia, however, there IS such a thing as Hellenistic Jews and it started at the time of Nehemiah/Ezra. Hellenistic Jews not speaking Hebrew/Aramaic was the reason for the Septuagint translation a couple hundred years before Christ. I would therefore appreciate removing the down vote from my answer as reputation is still important to me.

Comment: Jews didn't use Septuagint. They used Aramaic Peshitta Tanakh (Aramaic Old Testament). In Antiquities of Jews XX XI, Josephus states that he knew Greek more than any Jews in first century. But he still couldn't speak Greek with sufficient exactness due to the fact that he was so accustomed to speaking his own tongue. You should ask a question "Were there Hellenized Jews in first century AD?" and I will answer it. I cannot explain everything here.

Comment: I already know there were Hellenized Jews in the first Century, so why should I ask it? The book of Acts in the Bible records a dispute between the Palestinian Jews and the Hellenized Jews within the early church (Acts 6). If the Jews didn't use the Septuagint, why would 72 rabbis have translated it? The gentiles didn't consider the Hebrew Scriptures to have been of value. As mentioned before, Josephus didn't consider Hellenistic Jews to be true Jews, so you have to filter his comments in that regard.

Comment: There were no Hellenized Jews in first century AD. Talmud claims 72 rabbis translated from Hebrew into Greek for Septuagint. But Talmud is filled with absurd informations. You should ask if there are any tamperings in Greek NT manuscripts. I will show you that there were no Hellenistic Jews in first century Israel.

Comment: Yes there have been "tamperings" with the New Testament manuscripts. But when this happens, it is easily detectable because of the thousands of other Greek Manuscripts of the NT. ALL Greek Manuscripts of the book of Acts affirms the existence of Hellenists. I will choose to believe the Holy Bible over a Jewish priest who betrayed the Jewish soldiers under his command in order to gain a Roman pardon for his part in the Jewish Revolt. You can choose who to believe of course.

Comment: Josephus didn't betray any Jewish soldiers. He was an honest man. Josephus begged Jews to surrender. Otherwise he told them that Romans will have no choice but to destroy them. Greek NT manuscripts tried to cover up the truth by replacing Arameans with Greeks in New Testament.

Comment: Josephus ordered all the soldiers to commit suicide rather than surrender to the Romans. After everyone else killed themselves, he surrendered himself to the Romans and became a hero. He was a first century Benedict Arnold. But that is irrelevent. The Holy Scriptures take precedence over any man when it comes to discerning the truth.

Comment: That's not the way it happened. Read his book Jewish Wars properly. You are using Greek NT manuscripts which is filled with deceptive natures. Ask the difference between Aramaic NT and Greek NT and you will see how deceptive Greek NT is and how truthful both Aramaic NT and Josephus are.

Comment: The Aramaic New Testament is a translation of the Greek New Testament. Greek manuscripts outdate the Aramaic New Testament. If you read anything from the earkly Church fathers, they always quote the Greek New Testament, never quote the Aramaic. This is because the Aramaic NT had not been translated yet!

Comment: It is not a translation of Greek NT manuscript. Greek NT manuscripts are translated from Aramaic NT manuscripts. If you want to ask a question, then ask - "Was New Testament written in Greek or Aramaic?" I will answer with facts.

Comment: I have heard all of it before. My former pastor believes the Aramaic is the original. However, all the historical facts point to the Greek NT being the original. Even the Syriac Church, which uses the Peshitta as its standard Bible, acknowledges that the Peshitta is a translation. Only a fringe group of Messianics and Hebraic roots Christians hold the view that the Peshitta is the original.

Comment: There are no historical facts that Greek NT is the original. Those are the claims of so called Church Fathers who claim that Greek NT is the original. They states that Greek NT is the original. But they can't prove it. That's why I want you to ask the question. I can answer them with dozens of evidences about the originality of Aramaic.

Comment: Also, Murdocks translation of the Peshitta also acknowledges the existence of Hellenized Jews, which he calls Grecian Jews: "And in those days, when the disciples had become numerous, the Grecian disciples murmured against the Hebrew, because their widows were neglected in the daily ministration [to the needy]." (Acts 6:1, Murdock)

Comment: I'm done with this conversation. All the historical facts prove both that the Greek NT is the original and that there Hellenistic Jews in the first century. These are off topic of this question anyways. End of discussion, Have a good day, and may Theos (Greek: "God") bless you.

Comment: Grecian Jews refers to Jews lived in Greek regions. They spoke Aramaic and knew only "some" Greek. This is just like me. I am an Indian living in America. But my language is Malayalam. I speak English as second language. There are thousands of Hispanics living in Florida and they don't speak English. They speak Spanish.

Comment: Greek NT is filled with fallacies and you call them historical facts. The only fact I see is that you don't have the courage to ask a question on "Was New Testament written in Greek or Aramaic?"

Comment: @konwayk - there were Jews from all over the Roman Empire present at the time of the Crucifixion, as they were *still* there on the Day of Pentecost, as recorded in Acts 2 :)

Comment: I agree with you. But we know that Jews took their Aramaic language wherever they went. In Acts 21, when Jews in Asia (Turkish regions) saw Paul at temple of Jerusalem, they called "Men of Israel" for help in Aramaic. Asia refers to Turkish region in first century AD. Here is the link to the map - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1stMithritadicwar89BC.png

Comment: @ByronArn, Thought this dialogue was beneficial, certainly deserving of my positive vote!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, and somewhat simpler, explanation is that many of those present knew very well that Jesus was quoting the opening line of the 22nd Psalm; but through their willful blindness, determined to avoid seeing that Psalm's fulfillment manifested in the tableau in front of them, they allowed Satan to fill their heads with a suitably distracting (though somewhat illogical) interpretation of why Jesus was quoting it.