# How would I write Jesus in in ancient Aramaic?

Tags: history, language, aramaic

I would like to know how to print out Jesus is God in Aramaic specifically the Aramaic Christ spoke.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Your question has been down-voted (not by me) because it doesn't fit with our guidelines for asking questions.  Please take our Tour to find out what sort of questions are acceptable: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

**How to print out Jesus is God in Aramaic specifically the Aramaic Christ spoke?**

The dialect of Aramaic Jesus spoke with his disciples was very different than the dialect of Aramaic spoken at Jerusalem. Jesus spoke Galilean Aramaic a dialect spoken natively north of Judaea. There is evidence that this dialect sounded harsh and distorted to the ears of Jerusalem Aramaic speaker. The distinct accent would immediately give away a Galilean in Jerusalem.

In the Scriptures of the New Testament, Jesus uses the following names when he refers to God, *Elōah* **(אלוה)**.

The Ancient Aramaic script for Jesus is *Yeshua* **(ישוע)**.

The following articles may be of interest to some:

- [God in Aramaic](https://www.aramaic.rocks/2012/06/god-in-aramaic.html)
- [Elahi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elahi#:%7E:text=Elah%20means%20%22god%22%2C%20with,%22%E1%BC%90%CE%BB%CF%89%CE%90%20%E1%BC%90%CE%BB%CF%89%CE%90%22%20eloi%20eloi.)
- [What word did Jesus use for God in Aramaic?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/what-word-did-jesus-use-for-god-in-aramaic)
- [Jesus (name)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_(name))
- [What language did Jesus speak?](https://www.gotquestions.org/language-Jesus-speak.html)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your primary question, this is how you would write Jesus Christ in Scotland (using Scots Gaelic):

> Iosa Crìosd
> https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/scots-gaelic-word-for.html

However, that isn't what you meant, was it?  As to your question about Aramaic, here is some information I found:

> Jesus spoke Galilean Aramaic, natively the common spoken language of the people in area at the time. By that time Hebrew was long gone as a spoken language since the times that Jews were expelled to Babylon, being used almost exclusively as a language of liturgy. There they picked up and shifted to Aramaic, the second common language of the Persian Empire. Upon their return they brought their newly acquired language to Judaea.

> Today little is known about the Galilean dialect and it is currently being reconstructed and constantly being revised.

> The historical name of Jesus (Ιησούς) in Amaraic was Yeshua ישוע  or (ܝܫܘܥ) in Classical Syriac. In Eastern Syriac dialects there is the variation Isho (ܝܫܘܥ) written the same as Yeshua.

> Before he died on the cross Jesus cried out "Eli, Eli, lema sabachthani?" (which means "My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?").
> https://www.aramaic.rocks/2012/06/jesus-christ-in-aramaic.html

From this it may be possible for you to put together the Aramaic words for Jesus and for God and come up with an approximation of "Jesus is God" in Aramaic.